# Не работает функция перенаправления

Tags: php

В определенном файле создал функцию :

```
function face() {
if ($us['users_id'] != NULL) {
    header('Location: /index.php');
    exit;
}
}
```

в другом файле объявил переменную *$us* 
В нужном мне файле вывожу инклуды:

1. файл подключения к базе данных
2. Файл где объявлена переменная *$us*
3. Вывожу функцию `face();`

Но она не срабатывает.

По идее, если *id* пользователя не = NULL, должно перенапрвить на другую страницу.

*id* не = NULL - это я проверял.

Comment: Штатные телепаты ушли в отпуск, вам предлагается либо дождаться их либо представить нам код `другого файла`

Comment: Но уже сейчас можно заявить что в функции `face` никаким образом не объявлена переменная `$us`. Следовательно она NULL

Comment: а зачем вам код других файлов? ведь если код который должна выполнить функция срабатывает если его просто вставить в код нужно мне страницы. А вот если в код нужной мне страницы вставить _face();_ то код этой функции не выполняется почему то..

Comment: @Денис, попробуйте передать `$us` параметром функции `face()`.

Comment: так переменная _$us_ объявлена в другом файле, который выводится на нужной мне странице с помощью **include_once**

Comment: Код нужной вам функции выполняется. Просто выполняется там не то что вы ожидаете.

Comment: @Денис прочитайте про область видимости переменных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

О боже, что-то я совсем забыл добавить в функцию `global $us;` теперь все работает